# Составление формулы для задачи на комбинаторику

Tags: комбинаторика

Задача: написать программу, которая будет возвращать число способов разложить `n` шаров по `n-2` ящику. Шары разные, ящики не пустые.

Сложность: сама формула расчёта.

У меня получилось составить алгоритм, возвращающий число способов распределить `n-2` из `n` шаров по `n-2` ящикам, то есть, остаётся как-то распределить (а потом и подсчитать) ещё 2 шара.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

int fact(int N)
{
    if (N < 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0)
        return 1;
    return N * fact(N - 1);
}


int main()
{
    int n, rez=0;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    rez = fact(n)/2;
    printf_s("%d",rez);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Если шары разные, то сначала нужно выбрать n-2 шара из n, потом разложить эти n-2 шара по n-2 ящикам, а потом разложить оставшиеся 2 шара (0-2 шаров, если не обязательно раскладывать все шары, что допустимо по текущему условию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если шары в ящиках "валяются", т.е. их порядок внутри ящика не имеет значения, то при данных вводных возможны два расклада: один ящик содержит три шара, остальные по одному, либо два ящика содержат по два шара, остальные по одному.

Для первого случая существует C(n,3) выборок, (n-2)! перестановок, так что

```
F_3 = n! / (3!(n-3)!)  * (n-2)! = n! * (n-2) / 6
```

Для второго случая есть C(n,2) вариантов первой пары, С(n-2,2) вариантов второй и (n-2)!/2 перестановок (c учетом удвоения пар)

```
F_(2/2) = (n-2)! * n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) / 8
```

Итого

```
F(n) = n! * (n-2) / 6 + (n-2)! * n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) / 8 = 
       n! * (n-2) * (3*n-5) / 24
```

Для `n=3,4,5` получается: `(1, 14, 150)`

Сверимся с oeis - [есть такая буква](http://oeis.org/A037960) (нумерация сдвинута на 2)

Comment: Три шара в один ящик разными способами?

Comment: Если для n=3 результат должен быть больше 1, то скорее всего условие допускает раскладывать не все шары, а только такое количество, для которого каждый ящик содержит не менее одного шара. Другими словами, 2 шара можно не раскладывать. Тогда для n=3 будет 3 + 3 + 1 = 7

Comment: @cpp questions Если допускается раскладывать не все шары и это не оговорено в условии - это, скажем так, весьма нетипичная задача по комбинаторике

Comment: Откуда два ящика???

Comment: Сделайте новый вопрос с новым условием, на заданный я уже ответил, а изменение "экзотично".

Comment: Первоначальное условие описывало довольно стандартную и в общем случае непростую комбинаторную задачу (есть такие задачи по нахождению количества и по перечислению всех вариантов). То, что вы додумали со введением пустого ящика - кардинально меняет задачу.

Comment: @MBo решение описано хорошо, всё понял, кроме одного момента: `(n-2)!/2 перестановок (c учетом удвоения пар)` - почему мы должны делить здесь на `2`? И не получили ли мы эту `2` из `2!`?

Comment: Можно считать, что эта двойка соответствует 2!. С помощью сочетаний мы уже получаем все возможные пары, и при перестановках их обмен не нужен (AB CD E и CD AB E).